# Creating the design matrices for a canonical correlation analysis

Tags: functional-programming, matrix, statistics, r

I have this code to generate symmetric matrices for testing how the design of the canonical correlation analysis I am performing works out. This is a extension of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949277/2886003)

Each row of the matrix represent a dataset (it is symmetric), and if the value is 0 it means no interaction between the datasets, if it is higher that there is an interaction. The end goal of this code is just to make a grid search of the design that explains better the data I have. 
However as I need to come up with different designs adding more datasets or less I would like to know how to improve this into a function that would be more general, specially the nested for loops part (If I test it with 5 datasets I add more `for` loops and then more `unlist` at the end).

Initial matrix (I usually work with 4 datasets):

```
C <-  matrix(0,ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
```

Weights for the interactions of each dataset (4 to avoid to many combinations):

```
nweight <- 4
weight <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = nweight)
```

Initiate the list that will contain the matrices

```
C_list <- vector("list", nweight)
cweight <- as.character(weight)
names(C_list) <- cweight
```

Loop for each position I want to change to obtain all the combinations of weights I want to test.

```
for(i1 in cweight) {
  C_list[[as.character(i1)]] <- vector("list", nweight)
  names(C_list[[(i1)]]) <- cweight
  for (i2 in cweight) {
    C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]] <- vector("list", nweight)
    names(C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]]) <- cweight
    for (i3 in cweight) {
      C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]][[(i3)]] <- vector("list", nweight)
      names(C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]][[(i3)]]) <- cweight
      for(i4 in cweight) {
        C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]][[(i3)]][[(i4)]] <- vector("list", nweight)
        names(C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]][[(i3)]][[(i4)]]) <- cweight
        for (i5 in cweight) {
          C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]][[(i3)]][[(i4)]][[(i5)]] <- vector("list", nweight)
          names(C_list[[(i1)]][[(i2)]][[(i3)]][[(i4)]][[(i5)]]) <- cweight
          for (i6 in cweight) {
            C[1, 2] <- as.numeric(i1)
            C[2, 1] <- as.numeric(i2)

            C[1, 3] <- as.numeric(i2)
            C[3, 1] <- as.numeric(i2)

            C[1, 4] <- as.numeric(i3)
            C[4, 1] <- as.numeric(i3)

            C[2, 3] <- as.numeric(i4)
            C[3, 2] <- as.numeric(i4)

            C[2, 4] <- as.numeric(i5)
            C[4, 2] <- as.numeric(i5)

            C[4, 3] <- as.numeric(i6)
            C[3, 4] <- as.numeric(i6)
            C_list[[i1]][[i2]][[i3]][[i4]][[i5]][[i6]] <- C
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unlist the list of list of list of ... nested matrices to end up with a long list of matrices with the weights for each dataset

```
C_list2 <- unlist(unlist(unlist(unlist(unlist(C_list, FALSE, FALSE), 
                                       FALSE, FALSE), FALSE, FALSE), 
                         FALSE, FALSE), FALSE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you want to move away from `for` loops for two reasons:

1. your number of `for` loops depends on your number of datasets, so using `for` loops prevents you from generalizing your code to any number of datasets.
2. many `for` loops will likely slow down your code execution when working with a larger number of datasets.

I think the key to vectorizing your `for` loops is to use the `expand.grid` function. If you have

```
n <- 4
```

datasets, then you have

```
p <- n * (n - 1) / 2    # 6
```

degrees of freedom (the number of `for` loops in your code, or the number of items on the lower triangle of each matrix). If for each of these you can pick among

```
w <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = n)
```

then you can build the matrix of all possible combinations by doing:

```
W <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(w), p)))
```

Here `W` is a big matrix with 4096 rows, each row representing a different combination of your `(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6)` variables:

```
> head(W)
          Var1      Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
[1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0
[2,] 0.3333333 0.0000000    0    0    0    0
[3,] 0.6666667 0.0000000    0    0    0    0
[4,] 1.0000000 0.0000000    0    0    0    0
[5,] 0.0000000 0.3333333    0    0    0    0
[6,] 0.3333333 0.3333333    0    0    0    0
```

These `6` columns are only part of the `n * n = 16` values needed in each matrix. We can expand using the following:

```
X <- matrix(1:(n*n), n, n) # pattern matrix of indices
A <- matrix(0, nrow(W), n * n)
A[,    X[lower.tri(X)]] <- W
A[, t(X)[lower.tri(X)]] <- W
```

`A` is similar to `W` in that it is a matrix with `4096` rows, but each row now has the `n * n = 16` values of a symmetric matrix.

From there, you can reshape `A` into a 3D array:

```
dim(A) <- c(nrow(W), n, n)
```

and your `4096` matrices can be accessed as follows:

```
A[1, , ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0

A[10, , ]
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3] [,4]
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667    0
# [2,] 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
# [3,] 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
# [4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0

A[4096, , ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    0    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    0
```

If I were you I would probably stop here, i.e., keep the data in this form. A 3d array might allow you to continue writing vectorized code if the rest of your analysis allows for it. However if you absolutely want a list of matrices, you can do:

```
C_list2 <- lapply(seq(nrow(A)), function(i) A[i, , ])
```

(note that the order of the matrices in my data and yours do not match. Let me know if this is a concern, it's probably a matter of reorganizing the rows and/or columns of the `W` matrix.)